# Using Sequence in non Id field In jpa and Sql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, mapping

My JPA Entity contiens a non id field named counter, the value of this field is getted from Sql server sequence.

How can i represente this requirement in my JPA mapping of the entity ?

I note that i can't add/modify the dabatabase objects ( triger/ function / procedure ), the solution must be bassed on JPA

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA does not define @GeneratedValue on non-ID fields. However some JPA implementations (e.g the one I use DataNucleus JPA) do allow it, hence if using one of those implementations then you could just annotate the field as SEQUENCE.

Comment: I create a method that get the next value from the sequence ! Thanks